# How to add a new line where a string has an Uppercase char?

Tags: php, regex

I'm restoring headers from a parsed PDF text. I want to add a new line where an uppercase char is. How to do this with regex?

This is an excerpt of the text:

```
... Aanpassing aanvullend verkeersreglement. Advies - GoedkeuringMotiveringAanleiding en contextDe Zakstraat in het district ...
```

`$matches = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z])/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

I want:

```
... Goedkeuring
#Motivering#
#Aanleiding en context#
De Zakstraat ....
```

Comment: why `De Zakstraat` is in single line then ?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])` https://regex101.com/r/vyyfJi/1 see https://3v4l.org/2pdKm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z])` asserts that what is on the right is a single uppercase A-Z, 1+ times a lowercase a-z and then again an uppercase A-Z.

That will not split before `Aanleiding` because there is no ending uppercase case.

What you might do is omit the `[A-Z]` at the end of your pattern and prepend a positive lookbehind `(?<=[a-z])` to check for a lowercase char a-z.

The pattern might look like:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oE14h/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/2pdKm)

```
$text = "... Aanpassing aanvullend verkeersreglement. Advies - GoedkeuringMotiveringAanleiding en contextDe Zakstraat in het district ...";
$matches = preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ... Aanpassing aanvullend verkeersreglement. Advies - Goedkeuring
    [1] => Motivering
    [2] => Aanleiding en context
    [3] => De Zakstraat in het district ...
)
```